# iPad IOS 4.2 popViewControllerAnimated animation is now vertical

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios4

When I updated iPad to iOS 4.2.1 animation for popViewControllerAnimated suddenly changed from slide left to right to vertical slide top to bottom. The pushViewControllerAnimated works as expected.

```
- (void)back
{   
    if ([self currentLevel] > 0) 
    {
        [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        [[self model]setSlideDirection:kBackward];
        [[self model]setSlideNum:[self currentLevel] - 1];

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you apply some sort of transform to your view?

Comment: No I didn't apply any transform.

Comment: Seems to me to be some sort of a bug. It worked fine in 3.2.

Comment: Also seeing that rightSwipes are firing twice be gesture. That's new. Those were fine in 3.2

Answer (score 3):

I guess I have found at least one solution - since it now works for me. Does your NavigationController override ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation? If so ensure that all "child" view controller you push / pop from / to the navigation stack also override ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation with the same result!

Comment: What a weird bug.  Luckily this fixes it.  Thanks!